# I need to figure out a pattern

Tags: pattern-recognition

Finish the Pattern to the nearest number: 0 0 3 20 115
I need to add in a few more sentences to make this problem meet the standards. If you could solve this pattern, it would help me out alot, its sort of stumping me.

Comment: Were you thinking $n! - n$ as in http://oeis.org/A005096?

Answer (score 3):

According to a Chinese website I found on Google:

$$(0+0)\cdot2=0$$

$$(0+1)\cdot3=3$$

$$(3+2)\cdot4=20$$

$$(20+3)\cdot5=115$$

$$(115+4)\cdot 6=714$$

Answer (score 2):

0, 0, 3, 20, 115, 714, 5033, 40312, 362871, 3628790, 39916789, 479001588, 6227020787, 87178291186, ...

http://oeis.org/A005096

The sequence is given by $n!-n$.